# Remove first 3 characters from column A in a CSV, skipping Header with spaces

Tags: powershell, csv

I am attempting to remove the first 3 characters from column A, header "Emp ID".
Characters are EID followed by a string of digits. Another column contains UName that may also have EID followed by digits. What I have is below, but it's not even close.

```
$CSV = Import-Csv "Export.csv" | Select -skip 1

$CSV |
  % { $_ -replace '^...' } |
  Export-Csv "ExportNEW.csv"
```

Result is no changes.

Comment: You need to use the name of the column.  To see names use : $CSV | Format-Table

Answer (score 1):

```bash
Import-Csv Export.csv |
  ForEach-Object { 

    # Update the 'Emp ID' property (column value)
    $_.'Emp ID' = $_.'Emp ID' -replace '^...'

    # ... update other column values analogously.

    # Pass the modified object (row) through.
    $_

  } |
  Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8 ExportNEW.csv
```

- I've omitted `Select -Skip 1`, as I'm not sure you really want to skip the first *data* row (the *header* row isn't output as such by [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv); the information there is simply used to determine the *property names*, based on the column names, to use for the objects that the data rows are parsed into.
- I've added `-NoTypeInformation` and `-Encoding utf8` to the [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) call for use in *Windows PowerShell*, which by default emits a typically undesired *comment* row, and defaults to ASCII(!) encoding; adjust the encoding as needed; note that `-Encoding utf8` invariably creates a file *with* a BOM.

  - Neither parameter is necessary in [PowerShell (Core) 7+](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md) anymore, which no longer emits this comment row and (consistently) defaults to UTF-8, albeit *BOM-less* UTF-8; use `-Encoding utf8bom` in case you do want the BOM.

Comment: Thank you! This resolved the issue. I'm just getting familiar with PS editing CSVs.